# Variance of a random mixture of Gaussian random variables (I think the official solution might be incorrect)

Tags: probability

I think the official solution to a homework question may be incorrect. The question is:

$X_1,X_2$ are standard normal random variables. $U$ is a continuous uniform random variable with interval $[0,1]$.

$Z = UX_1 + (1-U)X_2$. I have to find $Var(Z)$.

Here is what I have done:

I want to find $Var(Z)$ by using $ Var(Z) = E(Var(Z|U)) + Var(E(Z|U)) $.

So I need to find $E(Z|U)$ and $E(Z^2|U)$.

The distribution of $Z$ given $U = u$ is simply normal with mean zero and variance $u^2 + (1-u)^2$. Therefore

$E(Z^k|U=u) = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{0.5}(u^2 + (1-u)^2)^{0.5}} z^k e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} dz$. This evaluates to $0$ for $k=1$ and $(u^2 + (1-u)^2)^{-0.5}$ for $k = 2$.

Since $Var(Z|U) = E(Z^2|U) - (E(Z|U))^2$ and $E(Z|U) = 0$ it follows that

$Var(Z|U) = E(E(Z^2 | U)) $ which is $E((U^2 + (1-U)^2)^{-0.5})$ where $U\sim Uniform(0,1)$

Hence $Var(Z|U) = \int_{0}^{1}(u^2 + (1-u)^2)^{-0.5}du \approx 1.25 $.

But the official solution is $\frac{2}{3}$. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The distribution of $Z$ given $U=u$ is simply normal with mean zero
>   and variance $u^2+(1-u)^2.$

That's right... and it tells you everything you need to know:
$$E(Z\mid U) = 0\\\operatorname{Var}(Z\mid U) = U^2 + (1-U)^2.$$ So you're massively overcomplicating things.

Then we have $$ \operatorname{Var}(Z) = E(\operatorname{Var}(Z\mid U)) + \operatorname{Var}(E(Z\mid U)) \\ = E(U^2+(1-U)^2) + 0\\=\int_0^1 (u^2 + (1-u)^2)du \\= 2/3 $$

(Looking at your work, one problem that jumps out apart from the over-complication is you seem to have forgotten to put the variance in the exponent of the Gaussian distribution. i.e. it's $e^{-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma^2}},$ not $e^{-z^2/2}.$)

Comment: Everything is so clear now! Thank you. And thank you so much for finding my mistake.